# Spring Boot Gradle project using Flink does not work

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-flink, slf4j

I have a Spring Boot Gradle project that uses LogBack log. I want it to support Flink, but Flink is using Log4j. When I started the project, it just stayed that way. The two don't work when combined.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.7.25'
    implementation 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:2.1.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.flink:flink-java:1.7.2'
    implementation 'org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-java_2.12:1.7.2'
    implementation 'org.apache.flink:flink-connector-kafka-0.10_2.12:1.7.2'
}
```

```
2019-04-03 11:40:20.788 [main] 
INFO com.example.server.flinkkafkademo03.FlinkKafkaDemo03Application [SpringApplication.java:679] - The following profiles are active: dev 
2019-04-03 11:40:23.798 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] 
INFO akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger [Slf4jLogger.scala:92] - Slf4jLogger started 2019-04-03 11:40:23.879 [flink-metrics-2] 
INFO akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger [Slf4jLogger.scala:92] - Slf4jLogger started 
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred 
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.flink.core.memory.HybridMemorySegment (file:/E:/Program%20Files/gradle-5.0/repository/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.flink/flink-core/1.7.2/184443282d6269261e2783d5797d2aafbe88253/flink-core-1.7.2.jar) to field java.nio.Buffer.address 
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.flink.core.memory.HybridMemorySegment 
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations 
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Comment: What is the issue ? What I see is just **INFO** and **WARNING**

Comment: If it is just about logback vs. log4j: Exclude log4j from your flink dependency (that should be possible from whatever build system you are using).